# what is the value of dispatch in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The Value should be returned by Reduce Store(Reducer). How Reducer is sending it to mapDispatchToProps method in container.

My Reducer looks like -

```
const Todos = (state=['FirstItem'],action) => {
switch(action.type) {

case 'ADD-TODO' :
    return [...state, action.payload];
default :
    return state;
}
return state
}
export default Todos
```

My mapDispatchToProps is receiving state inside the dispatch parameter here. and failing to dispatch because 'Dispatch is not a function here'

Code of mapDispatchToProps looks like this -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {addTodoItem} from '../ActionCreator/ActionCreator';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Todo from '../Todo';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        addItem : (text) =>(addTodoItem(text))
    },dispatch)
}

const AddTodoContainer =  connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Todo);

export default AddTodoContainer
```

Please tell me what should be the value of dispatch and how reduce store sends it.

Comment: How u invoking the `addItem ` from components?Please share the that part as well

Comment: I think I have figured it out. It has just worked now.  The problem was, Since there was not mapStatesToProp method, I just passed mapDispatchToProps.
However I should have pass null (for MapStatesToProps) and then mapDispatchToprops. That's why I was getting state in the dispatch function.

Also Dispatch function is being returned by createStore method of redux.

In case you want to look, how I am calling AddItem in the component - 

const Todo = ({addItem}) => (
)

Comment: I think,you already doing it `const AddTodoContainer =  connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Todo);
`

Comment: Didn't run the code after making this change. Just checked :)
Its working. Thanks

Comment: nice........ :)